# loadAppContextDataFromInbox error loading in application context from inbox NSFileReadNoPermissionError -> EACCES

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit, wcsession

I have been developing an app the works with the apple watch's workouts and an iPhone.  The app is written in swift and communication has been working properly for weeks while I add features.  I am suddenly getting the following error code when I try to run my app on my iPhone.

[WCFileStorage loadAppContextDataFromInbox] error loading in application context from inbox NSFileReadNoPermissionError -> EACCES

This error is being generated on a program that was working fine using the same code.  I believe the error is coming from the following line of code:

WCSession.default.updateApplicationContext(dictionary)

in the func shown below.

```
func sendAppStateToWatch(appState : String?) {

    if WCSession.isSupported() {

        if let appStatus = appState {

            do {

                let dictionary = ["iOSAppState" : appStatus]
                try WCSession.default.updateApplicationContext(dictionary)
            } catch {

                print("sendActiveTimeToPhone() ERROR: \(error)")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This function has been working without problem for at least a month. Suddenly, I am getting the error shown above.  I have rebooted the watch, phone and Xcode without effect.  I suspect the error comes from  some privacy setting on the phone or watch that flipped, but looking around I cannot find the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was able to fix this error by uninstalling the app on my iPhone and installing it fresh.

Comment: After uninsatlling and installing ,i am still getting this issue. do you find any other solution for this issue. it is not a proper way to install it again and again